# Найти в строке слова с 2 и более одинаковыми буквами

Tags: php

```
$string = "Hello world! The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested.";
```

Нужно найти слова с 2 и более одинаковыми буквами(Hello, standart,...). Можно ли это сделать через регулярные выражения? И какими вообще способами можно это сделать?

Comment: Разбить по пробелам, удалить не буквенные символы. Потом в каждом слове проверять что следующая буква равна предыдущей. Например так.

Comment: Циклом пройтись по слову и проверить.

Comment: Уточните вопрос - имеются в виду вообще одинаковые буквы, или идущие подряд одинаковые буквы?

Comment: Вообще одинаковые буквы.

Comment: Тогда регулярками врядли

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, можно через регулярные выражения, например так:

```
\w*(\w)(?=\w*\1)\w*
```

Тест на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/UgPcK3/3)

При необходимости заменить `\w` на другой класс символов (например если не нужны цифры).

Расшифровка:

```
\w*        # Некоторое количество символов
(\w)       # Среди которых есть такой
(?=\w*     # После которого еще некоторые символы
\1)        # и точно такой же (ссылка назад)
\w*        # и потом могут быть еще какие то символы слова
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, сейчас розберусь с регуляркой. Потом еще поопробую через цикл.

Comment: Вот точно - век учись!

Comment: @Mike наверное, в начале и конце \b не повредит, чтоб целиком слово захватить

Comment: @Mike по привычке все на sqlfiddle решает, даже регулярки :D

Comment: @teran :) привычка страшная сила

Comment: @splash58 `\w*` захватит все, что может, жадности хватит

Answer (score -1):

Вот Вам точка отсчета для решения через циклы

```
$string = "Hello world! The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested.";
$words=explode(" ",$string);

foreach ($words as $word) {
    $letters=str_split($word);
    $letters=array_unique($letters);

    if (count($letters)!=strlen($word)) {
        $result[]=$word;
    }
} 

print_r($result);


Array
(
[0] => Hello
[1] => standard
[2] => 1500s
[3] => reproduced
[4] => interested.
)
```

Это не полностью готовое решение, тут еще нужно почистить от запятых и т.д., и решите что делать с цифрами, удалять их или оставить.

[Демо тут](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c49c3f7a49ce9436b230995b57f2249b04bea1b)